# objectiveC/CMTime - convert AVPlayer.duration to milliseconds

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avplayer, cmtime

I'm creating an app for playing a ringtone and I'd want to know the current time in milliseconds of the played ringtone every time.

CMTime cTime = player_.currentTime;
float currentTime = cTime.value / cTime.timescale;

That currentTime here gets the value in seconds.
How can I get the exact currentTime value but in milliseconds?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is a way to get current times in seconds, you can take 1000 times that and ther you have your miliseconds:

```
Float64 dur = CMTimeGetSeconds([player currentTime]);
Float64 durInMiliSec = 1000*dur;
```

Sadly you will have to use it as a `float` or `Float64` you can't use that result as a `CMTime`

Comment: But how can we pass this Float value in the following function? 
- (BOOL)insertTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange ofTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)track atTime:(CMTime)startTime error:(NSError **)error;
Because it takes CMTime as a parameter.

Comment: You can use the original time (in seconds) and create a CMTime with that value using the CMTimeMake function.

Comment: This decade-old answer still holds test of time. Much appreciated. Helped us solve an issue losing fraction of second in this [PR](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/421).

Answer (score 6):

I think that the accepted answer loses detail.  A more accurate way to get milliseconds would be the following:

```
let seconds : Double = Float64(time.value * 1000) / Float64(time.timescale)
```

If you convert to seconds first you'd lose precision.

Comment: This is incorrect. From Apple's documentation on CMTimeGetSeconds "The division is done in Float64, so the fraction is not lost in the returned result."

Answer (score 2):

CMTime.value and CMTime.timescale are both integers, so judging by your code, the result gets rounded and you don't get a precise timestamp. Try CMTimeGetSeconds instead.